# Identity server 4 not removing cookie

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have front app on angular 5 and backend api on c# using identity server. 
The problem is that when I click logout button, the token is removed and i am redirected to logout page.

But when I try to refresh main page, I am redirected to microsoftonline.com
authenticated automatically and  redirected back to main page
I am missing providing username and password here, and this occurs in chrome incognito.

What I noticed is that if I remove manually the cookie from microsoftonline.com
and repeat the process, this time I will be asked for username and password.

So first I tried to clean all cookies this way but it din't help

```
foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, "", new CookieOptions() { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });
}
```

bellow is my accountcontroller logout method and cookie screen

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutViewModel model)
{
    var idp = User?.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider)?.Value;
    var subjectId = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetSubjectId();

    if (idp != null && idp != IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider)
    {
        if (model.LogoutId == null)
        {
            model.LogoutId = await interaction.CreateLogoutContextAsync();
        }

        try
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
        }
    }

    // set this so UI rendering sees an anonymous user
    HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    // get context information (client name, post logout redirect URI and iframe for federated signout)
    var logout = await interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(model.LogoutId);

    var vm = new LoggedOutViewModel
    {
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
        ClientName = logout?.ClientId,
        SignOutIframeUrl = logout?.SignOutIFrameUrl
    };

    await persistedGrantService.RemoveAllGrantsAsync(subjectId, "angular2client");

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

[image]

Comment: See [Sign-out of External Identity Providers](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html) from the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are federating to Microsoft from your IdentityServer4 service? If so when you sign out of your identity service you should also give the user the option to sign out of the external provider (if it supports the relevant feature - it'd need to define an `end_session_endpoint` in the discovery document).

This functionality is supported by the standard OIDC middleware so you should be able to initiate signout by calling SignoutAsync() and passing the name of the scheme for the MS federated sign in.

Another option is to always send `prompt=login` in your external sign in requests and then check the `auth_time` claim you get back. That way to you force interactive sign in always and also verify when it happened.

Comment: at the end I replaced logout methods with those from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs and it started working

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the cookies from the HttpContext itself, using the extension method, provided by Identity Server, like [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html#adding-sign-out).

Or try this:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

in your Logout controller method.

3rd option (what I have in one of my test MVC clients is):

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    public void SignoutCleanup(string sid)
    {
        var cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
        var sidClaim = cp.FindFirst("sid");
        if (sidClaim != null && sidClaim.Value == sid)
        {
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
        }
    }
```

Where the `Logout` method is called on the button click, and the `SignoutCleanup` is the one that is passed to Identity Server, when registering the client as a `Client.BackChannelLogoutUri` (or `Client.FrontChannelLogoutUri`, or both, depending on your scenario).

**PS**: Now, in general I think that your approach is not right, but I don't know your full case, so I'm not judging you - just giving and advice.

For front-end clients (Angular, Vue, vanilla JS etc..) it is recommended to use the client-side [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library. And [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html) is the usage example. As I said - this is just an advice, but if you are in the very beginning of your authentication setup, I would recommend you to have a look.